# Why we can add String to combobox c#?

Tags: c#, string, combobox

`combobox.Items.Add(object item)`, so why we can use `combobox.Items.Add("Some text")`, although "Some text" is string, not object?

Comment: @Dmitry To be precise, pointers and managed references aren't objects.

Answer (score 9):

A `string` is a reference type, so it is an `object`. What combobox does is then call the `.ToString()` method of the object it receives to transform it in a string (to show it). The `ToString()` of a string simply returns the string.

Why is the `Add()` done in that way?

Let's look at an example using WinForms:

```
// A simple Person class, Name + Surname
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Surname;
    }
}

// cb is your ComboBox

// Three persons in the ComboBox
cb.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Bill", Surname = "Gates" });
cb.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Larry", Surname = "Ellison" });
cb.Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Peter", Surname = "Norton" });

// and then somewhere the user selects an item in the combobox
// and then we can

Person selectedPerson = (Person)cb.SelectedItem;
string selectedPersonDescription = cb.SelectedText;
```

You can retrieve not only the description of the selected item, but the "whole" selected item! You see the advantage? (as I said before, the "description" for the items is automatically calculated by the ComboBox class by using the `ToString()` method)

So clearly the ComboBox is saving the "whole" objects you `Add(...)` to it, and calculating the descriptions (with `ToString()`) to show to the user.

Answer (score 3):

It's thanks to polymorphism. Because `string` derives from `object`, you can pass it to the method, as well as any other instance of type deriving from `object` (which is almost everything).